# Right-clicking on an animation crashes Mathematica 8.04

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can anyone reproduce the following?

In MMA 8.04 in Windows Vista or Windows 7, right-clicking on
an animation while it is running crashes the entire Mathematica
session (kernel and front-end).

Comment: Can you give some example code?  I can't reproduce with `ListAnimate[Range[100]]`.

Comment: Example code is `Animate[Graphics3D[Point[{0, p, 0}]], {p, 1, 3}]` and right-click on the graphics while it is moving. It is fixed in the development version of Mathematica. I apologize for the inconvenience this has caused you.

Comment: FWIW this crashes on a Mac as well (10.6.8)

Comment: The crash can be worked around by wrapping the animation in an EventHandler which prevents the context menu from coming up.  E.g.,
    `EventHandler[
     Animate[Graphics3D[Point[{0, p, 0}]], {p, 1, 3}], {"MouseUp", 2} :> 
      Null]`
Which doesn't help much if you actually wanted the contextual menu, but it does prevent stray clicks from crashing the system if that's a problem for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too localized and outdated.